# When to return fetch() and when just using fetch() request?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

i'm starting in react native and one thing i've been wondering is that, sometime i see fetch is used like this:

```
createTodo(){
   fetch('http://192.168.1.34:3000/createTodo', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        content: this.state.noteText,
      }),
   }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var d = new Date();
        this.state.noteArray.push({
            'date':d.getFullYear()+
            "/"+(d.getMonth()+1) +
            "/"+ d.getDate(),
            'note': responseJson.data.content
        });
        this.setState({ noteArray: this.state.noteArray });
        this.setState({noteText:''});

        console.log(responseJson);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log('Shit! Error occured');
      });
}
```

this work fine.

and sometime it is:

```
return fetch(...)...
```

I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is Promise which returns another Promise. Resolved results passed to next `.then` input parameters. So in your example code, you can handle `response` values which is passed by `fetch` function.

You can return your `fetch` function when the client of `createTodo` wants to use the 'result' of `createTodo`. The 'result' is another Promise whose input parameters are from `createTodo`'s return values

- demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/548lwxzyn

Demo is just for showing that return value of Promise is another Promise. I hope you can get hint.